# Chrome Extension to clear network and console

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension The goal is to have a single 'button' and a context menu item that will clear network logs and console.

I've spent the day reading and experimenting but no joy.

I am not even sure now if this is even possible.

My question is. Is it possible to write an extension that will clear network logs and console?

Comment: 1) Assuming "network log" is in devtools, extensions can't clear it. 2) For console the only thing is `console.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks wOxxOm,
After a bit more reading, it cant be done. So closing this question. But happy to be proven wrong